# Set up an expiring credit system for a website

Tags: php, mysql

The site is built up with paid users (employers) and free users (job seekers).
Employers can buy credits to post jobs, however these credits need to expire in 28 days.

The relevant tables and fields are : Employers(id,account_email,credits) , Payments(id,amount,account)

Currently my system allows employers to purchase credits and they are added to there account. There is no limitation to the number of credits an employer can purchase. Credits will also be removed once a job is posted.

My idea : 
- add this as a new table : Credits(id,amount,account,expires).

```
// get an updated credit count before dislaying
$credit_update="DELETE FROM credits WHERE expires < NOW()";
$ret = mysqli_query($con,$credit_update);
```

Once they are removed from this newly created credits table is where I get lost. if the credits are used then I cannot just deduct the amount from the employers credits. I need a way to remove the credits if they are expired and still in the employers account. But I also need a way to differentiate between each batch of credits so i dont remove the incorrect batch.

Any help?

Comment: I would publish a schema, ( See **Section2** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) ) , and I would recommend treating it like an accounting system with debits and credits, never deleting a row like you appear to be doing. And use Intention Locks.

Comment: are there any accounting system examples you know of @Drew?

Comment: well from sox (sarbanes) compliance one doesn't delete rows. It is to everyone's benefit from an audit standpoint. You could have the decrement (attempt) be either a single row or batch. Alert them prior to attempt that insufficient funds exist. The lock is for concurrency issues (multiple people hitting same account at near the same time to avoid dirty reads). Like an atm machine would do it

Comment: You could maintain a rolled up balance at the account level but it would need to be secured with a lock. So that benefits from avoiding costly rollups each time. But like I said you have to have it nailed down with a lock.

Comment: @Drew currently Im just trying to make the ammount if it was not used expire from the account. Is there a way to just do that?

Comment: What I would do is treat the balance as a rollup and tag a `lastActivityDt` to the account level. The `lastActivityDt` would be a date or datetime. And it gets updated with any usage +/- ... could you go with that concept? Otherwise you seem to unnecessarily complicate matters for yourself

Comment: Imagine a cable bill. Each month there is usage, say, 39.99. Then an ocassional equipment bill. Then a payment from the user every 65 days right before they shut off service. Or a more complicated bill from some other relationship. When the payment comes in, say for 100, it is far wiser to just do debits and credits than to go out and match up bill and pd (with updates) to financial rows which violate SOX. Moreover, the paids and unpaids would probably have not transaction or audit history just overwrites and is error prone. Additionally there is overflow. So a mess

Comment: I understand in theory what im to do. Im just lost with the implementation of removing unused of a particular account

Comment: `and timestampdiff(minute,t1.transDate,date_add(now(),interval 4 hour))>42000`  (part of a where clause that uses hokey GMT offset and 42000 minute difference)

Comment: `datediff(now(),transDate)>24` (part of a where clause that finds transactions greater than 24 days ago)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125498/discussion-between-detectiveclarke-and-drew).

Comment: FYI, if you're based in the US, then there are laws that require [gift cards cannot expire for at least 5 years](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0182-gift-cards), so I'm not sure how much those laws might apply to your credit system.

Comment: @jeffPuckettll thanks jeff, however Im based in Europe I dont believe this affects me